# How to pause a youtube video on playing other video in page having multiples videos

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I have 6 videos in a page which are created using SWFOBJECT API.
    The requirement is to pause a video when another video is played.
    for ex: swfobject for video is

```
<DIV id=ytcontainer></DIV>
<SCRIPT>  
 swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/erDxb4IkgjM?version=3&f=user_uploads&app=youtube_gdatafs=1&rel=0&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=myytplayer", "ytcontainer", "660", "394", "8", null, null, {allowscriptaccess:"always",allowfullscreen:"true",wmode:"opaque"}, {id:"myytplayer"});
</SCRIPT>
like this way, i have 6 videos in a single page
```

below is the code for pausing video

```
<script>
swfobject.addLoadEvent(onYouTubePlayerReady);
            var status;
            var videostate2=0;  var videostate1=0;
           function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId)
            {
                var myPlayer1 = document.getElementById('myytplayer');
                var myPlayer2 = document.getElementById('qualityvideotrack');
                myPlayer1.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange1");
                myPlayer2.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange2");
            }

            function onytplayerStateChange1(newState)
            {
                   if(newState1==1)
                   {
                    videostate1=1;
                     pause();
                     }
                    else
                    videostate1=0;


                 return videostate1;
            }

            function pause()
            {
                var state;
                console.log("pause");
                var myPlayer2 = document.getElementById('qualityvideotrack');
                var myPlayer1 = document.getElementById('myytplayer');
                if(videostate2==1)
                {
                state=onytplayerStateChange2(videostate2);
                console.log("Player's new state:2 before pause "+state);
                if(state==1)
                myPlayer2.pauseVideo();
                }
                if(videostate1==1)
                {
                state=onytplayerStateChange1(videostate1);
                console.log("Player's new state:1 before pause "+state);
                if(state==1)
                myPlayer1.pauseVideo();
                }

            }

            function onytplayerStateChange2(newState2)
            {
            if(newState2==1)
            {
            videostate2=1;
            pause();
            }
            else
            videostate2=0;

        return videostate2;

            }

</script>
```

the above mentioned code won't work properly. However, if i write the code to stop one video while other is playing it works but vice versa not. Kindly suggest me.